# Is there any history magazine like "Foreign Policy" for politics?

Tags: ancient-history

I'm a college student. I'd like to read a history magazine (online preferred) that relates to History in the same way that "Foreign Policy" relates to Politics or "The Economist" relates to Economics. Are there any?

Comment: Welcome to History, your question is a bit off topic as you are not allowed, among many things defined in the FAQ, to ask for reference material, so, it may have to be closed.

Comment: As Russell said, welcome to History SE! Here, we use a Q&A format. This question does not really fit that format because no one answer will be right. Because of that, the community here has agreed that questions asking for recommendations are off-topic. If you have any objective questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: While it is true that this question does not fit our format, it seems to me that it would be useful to have such information. Because of that, I am going to convert this to a community wiki, which means we can provide answers that are more of a list of recommendations. I also edited it to make it more of a History topic because I feel like that was the intention.

Answer (score 3):

[BBC History Magazine](http://www.historyextra.com/) is my favourite history magazine. They have a great weekly podcast. There are online and print editions too.

Answer (score 0):

I get discounted subscription offers for [Current History](http://www.currenthistory.com/) all the time. Although I've never been a subscriber the material seems to be in the same style as say a [Foreign Policy](http://www.foreignpolicy.com/) or [Foreign Affairs](http://www.foreignaffairs.com/). It is focused on foreign affairs with a historical emphasis in the analysis.